# ModalBottomSheet moving too up when keyboard appears in Compose UI

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When Keyboard appears the ModalBottomSheet is moving too much to the top. Is there any way to stop this.

[image]

In my manifest I have

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and in my activity styles

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Base.Theme">
    <!-- Transparent system bars for edge-to-edge. -->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_cold_start</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "adjustResize" ?

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Yes. no effect.

Comment: It can be related to the height of your BottomSheet, if you haven't tried you can try the change of your bottomsheet.
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()